# RestSharp is not deserialising XML inline lists

Tags: xml, restsharp

Following XML works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<collection xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <workflow uuid="76b936ba-d52e-4304-b562-01676d35ad43">
        <name>Hello World</name>
        <description>Hello World Example</description>
        <links>
            <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows/self" rel="self"/>
            <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows" rel="list"/>
            <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows/jobs" rel="execute"/>
        </links>
    </workflow>
</collection>
```

but this is not...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<collection xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <workflow uuid="76b936ba-d52e-4304-b562-01676d35ad43">
        <name>Hello World</name>
        <description>Hello World Example</description>
        <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows/self" rel="self"/>
        <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows" rel="list"/>
        <ns2:link href="http://localhost/rest/workflows/jobs" rel="execute"/>
    </workflow>
</collection>
```

Here are my Class definitions:

```
    public class WfaCollection {
        public WfaWorkflow workflow { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("link")]
        public List<WfaLink> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class WfaWorkflow{
        public string uuid{get; set;}
    }

    public class WfaLink {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string rel { get; set; }
    }
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization#xmldeserializer-2) says inline XML lists jolly well should work... so what am I doing wrong? I have read many posts over deserialising, but none as trivial as mine! Makes me feel kinda dumb! Trouble is, I don't have control over the XML.

Answer (score 0):

By digging into the code, I have seen that my list is not being filled, because the method map() has the following:
    else if (type.IsGenericType) {
        ...
    }
    else if (type.IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(List<>))) {
        ...
    }

The second entry is not being executed because the first entry captures my List<> type definition. If I change the first entry if clause as follows, everything seems to work as expected:

else if (type.IsGenericType && !type.IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(List<>))) {...}

Is this a bug?